# Removing overlap hours from count of non-working days

Tags: sql, oracle

Need your help to complete this

Feb has totally 696 hrs

```
     Start Date        End Date 
S1 - 01-Feb-16 04:00 - 02-Feb-16 10:00 - 30hrs
S2 - 02-Feb-16 14:00 - 06-Feb-16 20:00 - 102hrs
S3 - 01-Feb-16 01:00 - 02-Feb-16 07:00 - 30hrs

                Total Worked hrs   - 162 hrs
```

As there is an overlap of 27 hrs available on S1 and S3, so total worked hrs - 135 hrs
The query result expected is 561 hrs

I have a challenge here with the code
1. code ready which does other part except ignoring the overlap hours, need your help. 
2. How can I limit the query to validate only for sysdate month

```
Query: 
SELECT ( ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'MM' ), 1 ) - TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'MM' )
         - SUM( End_Date - Start_Date ) ) * 24 AS Unworked_Hours
FROM   Trip_Dates;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Trip_Dates ( Start_Date, End_Date ) AS
SELECT TO_DATE( '2016-02-01 04:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' ), TO_DATE( '2016-02-02 10:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' ) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TO_DATE( '2016-02-02 14:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' ), TO_DATE( '2016-02-06 20:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' ) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TO_DATE( '2016-02-01 01:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' ), TO_DATE( '2016-02-02 07:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' ) FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
WITH Dates ( dt, start_end ) AS (
  SELECT GREATEST( start_date, TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'MM' ) ),
         1
  FROM   trip_dates
  WHERE  start_date < ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'MM' ), 1 )
  AND    end_date > TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'MM' )
  UNION ALL
  SELECT LEAST( end_date, ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'MM' ), 1 ) ),
         -1
  FROM trip_dates
  WHERE  start_date < ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'MM' ), 1 )
  AND    end_date > TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'MM' )
  ORDER BY 1, 2
)
,range_start_ends ( dt, start_end, range_start, range_end ) AS (
  SELECT d.*,
         CASE
           WHEN start_end =  1
            AND SUM( start_end ) OVER ( ORDER BY dt ) = 1
           THEN dt
           ELSE NULL
            END,
         CASE
           WHEN start_end = -1
            AND SUM( start_end ) OVER ( ORDER BY dt ) = 0
           THEN dt
           ELSE NULL
            END
  FROM   Dates d
),
worked_days ( worked_days ) AS (
  SELECT range_end - LAG( range_start ) IGNORE NULLS OVER ( ORDER BY dt )
  FROM   range_start_ends
)
SELECT ( ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'MM' ), 1 )
        - TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'MM' ) -
        SUM( worked_days )
       ) * 24 AS unworked_hours
FROM   worked_days;
```

**Results**:

```
UNWORKED_HOURS
--------------
           561
```