# Identify contiguous and discontinuous date ranges

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table named x . The data is as follows.

```
Acccount_num    start_dt    end_dt
A111326      02/01/2016    02/11/2016
A111326      02/12/2016    03/05/2016
A111326      03/02/2016   03/16/2016
A111331      02/28/2016   02/29/2016
A111331      02/29/2016   03/29/2016
A999999      08/25/2015   08/25/2015
A999999      12/19/2015   12/22/2015
A222222      11/06/2015   11/10/2015
A222222      05/16/2016   05/17/2016
```

Both A111326 and A111331 should be identified as contiguous data and A999999 and
A222222 should be identified as discontinuous data.In my code I currently use the following query to identify discontinuous  data. The A111326 is also erroneously identified as discontinuous data. Please help to modify the below code so that A111326  is not identified as discontinuous data.Thanks in advance for your help.

```
(SELECT account_num
                FROM (SELECT account_num,
                             (MAX (
                                 END_DT)
                              OVER (PARTITION BY account_num
                                    ORDER BY START_DT))
                                START_DT,
                             (LEAD (
                                 START_DT)
                              OVER (PARTITION BY account_num
                                    ORDER BY START_DT))
                                END_DT
                        FROM x
                         WHERE (START_DT + 1) <=
                                (END_DT - 1))
               WHERE START_DT < END_DT);
```

Answer (score 2):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE accounts ( Account_num, start_dt, end_dt ) AS
SELECT 'A', DATE '2016-02-01', DATE '2016-02-11' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', DATE '2016-02-12', DATE '2016-03-05' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', DATE '2016-03-02', DATE '2016-03-16' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', DATE '2016-02-28', DATE '2016-02-29' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', DATE '2016-02-29', DATE '2016-03-29' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', DATE '2015-08-25', DATE '2015-08-25' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', DATE '2015-12-19', DATE '2015-12-22' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'D', DATE '2015-11-06', DATE '2015-11-10' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'D', DATE '2016-05-16', DATE '2016-05-17' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'E', DATE '2016-01-01', DATE '2016-01-02' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'E', DATE '2016-01-05', DATE '2016-01-06' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'E', DATE '2016-01-03', DATE '2016-01-07' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
WITH times ( account_num, dt, lvl ) AS (
  SELECT Account_num, start_dt - 1,  1 FROM accounts
UNION ALL
  SELECT Account_num, end_dt,       -1 FROM accounts
)
, totals ( account_num, dt, total ) AS (
  SELECT account_num,
         dt,
         SUM( lvl ) OVER ( PARTITION BY Account_num ORDER BY dt, lvl DESC )
  FROM   times
)
SELECT Account_num,
       CASE WHEN COUNT( CASE total WHEN 0 THEN 1 END ) > 1
            THEN 'N'
            ELSE 'Y'
            END AS is_contiguous
FROM   totals
GROUP BY Account_Num
ORDER BY Account_Num;
```

**Output**:

```
ACCOUNT_NUM IS_CONTIGUOUS
----------- -------------
A           Y
B           Y
C           N
D           N
E           Y
```

**Alternative Query**:

*(It's exactly the same method just using `UNPIVOT` rather than `UNION ALL`.)*

```
SELECT Account_num,
       CASE WHEN COUNT( CASE total WHEN 0 THEN 1 END ) > 1
            THEN 'N'
            ELSE 'Y'
            END AS is_contiguous
FROM   (
  SELECT Account_num,
         SUM( lvl ) OVER ( PARTITION BY Account_Num
                           ORDER BY CASE lvl WHEN 1 THEN dt - 1 ELSE dt END,
                                    lvl DESC
                         ) AS total
  FROM   accounts
  UNPIVOT ( dt FOR lvl IN ( start_dt AS 1, end_dt AS -1 ) )
)
GROUP BY Account_Num
ORDER BY Account_Num;
```

Comment: I like this pattern using the running total on the date and level.  I agree this is more full proof and handles the issue of when a 3rd row is contiguous while second is not. Thanks for the answer and note I will probably use this again some time.

Comment: @Matt - Its adapted from my answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35521818/1509264) (which extracts the start and end dates of overlapping ranges using the first two parts of the above method and `LAG(...) IGNORE NULLS`).

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
       AccountNumber
       ,CASE
          WHEN
             LAG(End_Dt) OVER (PARTITION BY AccountNumber ORDER BY End_Dt) IS NULL THEN 0
          WHEN
             LAG(End_Dt) OVER (PARTITION BY AccountNumber ORDER BY End_Dt) >= Start_Dt - 1 THEN 0
          ELSE 1
       END as discontiguous 
    FROM
       #Table
)

SELECT
    AccountNumber
    ,CASE WHEN SUM(discontiguous) > 0 THEN 'discontiguous' ELSE 'contiguous' END
FROM
    cte
GROUP BY
    AccountNumber;
```

One of your problems is that your contiguous desired result also includes overlapping date ranges in your example data set.  Example `A111326` Starts on `3/2/2016` but ends the row before on `3/5/2015` meaning it overlaps by 3 days.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution. It really worked.  I do have data that is contiguous and overlapping .But this works.

Comment: yeah I changed the query when I noticed the overlapping to allow for it to be counted as continuous.  If in the future you ever don't want to include overlapping change >= Start_Dt - 1 to = Start_Dt - 1.  Glad it worked if you could accept the answer it would be appreciated (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Try the rows `'E', DATE '2016-01-01', DATE '2016-01-02'`; `'E', DATE '2016-01-05', DATE '2016-01-06'`; and `'E', DATE '2016-01-03', DATE '2016-01-07'` it outputs `discontiguous` when it is actually `contiguous`.

Comment: @MT0 I was going to ask you to post your code because I didn't even see the dates you where discussing but then I figured out the case you where trying to present.  Okay so that is interesting and yes it would break down due to the 3rd record/example overlapping fully the one prior and being contiguous.  I guess given the dataset does have some overlap it is fair to assume it might overlap fully from a 3rd to a second record...I can think of a few other ways to write this I guess I will look at it  again....